Strange Mid function
I see a formula for Mid function like this:
=MID(E2,6,10^3)
And here are results:
2024W45 -> 45
2024W47 -> 47
2024W46- > 46
2025W2 -> 2
Can someone help to explain me what is "10^3" in this case? This is the first your texttime i've seen that.
I just see that formula on a facebook page about excel. I tried to search on google with keyword like "advanced mid function", "mid function with "^"" but i couldn't find anything about it.

It means 10 to the power of 3. In other words: 1000. Try entering 10^3 into the google searchbar, it will actually give you this answer in a calculator.

i mean in mid function it still means 1000? and what is the meaning of 1000 in this case?

=MID(E2,6,10^3) is the same as: =MID(E2,6,1000). So it will return everything from the 6th character until 1000 characters after that. Kind of a hacky way to get everything from the 6th character untill whatever characters there are left on that string.

 =MID(E2,6,10^3) 

Is parsing the string in E2 to get characters from position 6 to position 10^3 or 1000.
Likely this is being used to say "Get every character from position 6 to the end of the string, regardless of how long the string is" which is a little silly as 10^3 is just as many characters as 1000 so it's a failure at code-golf and a failure at being supportable since it's clearly more confusing than just putting 1000 in there.
If you want to stick with this way of writing this formula, the character limit of a cell is 32727, so it would be more elegant to do the following:
=MID(E2, 6, 2^15)


Thank you so much :)). btw, can you help me what "{}" in this formula means: INDEX($D$4:$O$4,MATCH(TRUE,D5:O5<>"",0)),{"N","TCN","Đ","TCĐ"},0)+1)

{} is an "Array constant". In this case, instead of entering values "N", "TCN", etc into a range on a spreadsheet and then referencing that range in the formula, the author just skipped the spreadsheet part and specified the values directly with an array constant.

Is it a failure at code-golf though? ;)
